# Check if first array's item is in second array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, dictionary

I am building a simple react app and I am kind of stuck on a problem.

**What I am trying to do :-**

I am trying to check if `firstArray`'s (separate dict inside) item is in `secondArray` and when I run the loop then checking if is working fine But I am also trying to get item which is not in the array. But it is showing unexpected results in else statement.

I have tried many times with creating different array every time but it is showing same strange results in else statement.

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {

   const firstArray = [
    {
      "name" : "Blog 1"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Blog 2"
    },
   ]   

   const secondArray = [
    {
      "name" : "Blog 1"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Blog 2"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Blog 3"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Blog 4"
    },
   ]

  for (var k = 0; k < firstArray.length; k++) {
    for (var l = 0; l < secondArray.length; l++) {
      if (secondArray[l].name === firstArray[k].name) {
        // Getting items which are in the same array
        console.log(secondArray[l].name)
      } 
      else {
        // Getting items which are not in array
        console.log(secondArray[l])
      }
    }
  }

   render() {
       return (
          <div>Check below</div>
       )
   }
}
```

When I try to run the above code then it is showing,

**console.log. In `if` statement statement**

```
{name: 'Blog 1'}
{name: 'Blog 2'}
```

**console.log. In `else` statement statement**
It is showing strange results. And I am trying to get results which are not in the first array

```
{name: 'Blog 1'}
{name: 'Blog 2'}
{name: 'Blog 3'}
{name: 'Blog 1'}
{name: 'Blog 2'}
{name: 'Blog 3'}
{name: 'Blog 1'}
{name: 'Blog 2'}
{name: 'Blog 3'}
{name: 'Blog 1'}
{name: 'Blog 2'}
{name: 'Blog 3'}
```

I have no idea why it is showing that result but it is showing this for hours.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce it [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-lehmann-bu8z2d?file=/src/index.js). If you can then please share link with us.

Comment: Can you please share the firstArray and the desired result.

Comment: @A1exandrBelan, I have already uploaded it

Comment: @DecPK, What are you trying to say ? Sorry I didn't understand you

Answer (score 0):

To determine if the item in the 2nd array is in the 1st array or not you can use a flag. Set it `false` before inner `for` and then `true` if the item exists. Finally check it after inner `for`.

```
 for (var k = 0; k < secondArray.length; k++) {
    var exists = false;
    for (var l = 0; l < firstArray.length; l++) {
      if (secondArray[k].name === firstArray[l].name) {
        exists = true;
        break;
      } 
    }
    if (exists){
        console.log(secondArray[k].name + " exists");
    } else {
      console.log(secondArray[k].name + " doesn't exist");
    }
 }
```

Comment: It's not working, It is showing undefined because `exists` is outsite *k* `loop counter`

Answer (score 0):

Your **else** statement will work every time when `secondArray[k].name === firstArray[l].name` is false. Actually you are not checking if `secondArray[k]` is in first array, but you are checking if it equals to every item in the first array or not.

If I got you right you are trying to do is this:

```
const commonElements = secondArray.filter(secondElement => 
    firstArray.some(firstElement => firstElement.name === secondElement.name)
)
```

As a result you will get all elements that appear in both `firstArray` and `secondArray`

Comment: It is still not working.

Comment: You must put this code instead of your loops. Then do what you want with the elements of `commonElements` array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have asked similar question related to this with more easy explaning in brief what i am trying to do , [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73334680/two-map-statement-within-one-return-with-if-array-contains-items-from-another-ar)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what kind of result you are expecting. Here's what I can get.

```js
const firstArray = [{name: "Blog 1"},{name: "Blog 2"}];
const secondArray = [{name: "Blog 1"},{name: "Blog 2"},{name: "Blog 3"},{name: "Blog 4"}];

secondArray.forEach(({ name: second}) => {
    const status = firstArray.some(({ name: first}) => first === second) 
      ? 'exists' 
      : 'does not exist';
      
    console.log(`${second} - ${status} in the first array`);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I have asked similar question related to this with more easy explaning in brief what i am trying to do , [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73334680/two-map-statement-within-one-return-with-if-array-contains-items-from-another-ar)

Comment: I have no idea why But It is rendering twice, I mean it is showing results two times. I have also turned off `StrictMode`