# Two map statement within one return with if array contains items from another array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, dictionary

I am building a simple blog app and I am trying to check if blog is in liked blogs array in return function. So I have created `two array`, one of `all blogs` and another of `liked blogs` and I am trying to show message that "Blog is liked" But `two map` functions in return statement is showing unexpected results or showing strange multiple results.

App.js

```
class Blogs extends React.Component {

   const all_blogs = [
     {"blog_title" : "First Blog"},
     {"blog_title" : "Second Blog"},
     {"blog_title" : "Third Blog"},
     {"blog_title" : "Fourth Blog"},
     {"blog_title" : "Fifth Blog"},
   ]


   const liked_blogs = [
     {"blog_title" : "Second Blog"},
     {"blog_title" : "Third Blog"},
   ]


    render() {
       return (

         <div>

             {
                 all_blogs.map(blog =>
                     liked_blogs.map(liked_blog => {

                          if (blog.blog_title === liked_blog.blog_title) {

                             return (
                               <div>This blog is liked</div>
                             )
                          } else {
                               <div>This blog is NOT liked</div>
                          }
                }
             }

         </div>

      )
   }
}
```

I am trying to check if `all_blogs` blog is in `liked_blogs` liked or not in liked, and If blog is liked then show return `div` then if not then show else `div`

I have tried many times but it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nested map will `return` multidimention array which will not output the expected result, you need the `some` method to find if the `blog` exists in the `linked_blogs` or not, then conditionally show the message.

```js
class Blogs extends React.Component {

  const all_blogs = [
    {"blog_title" : "First Blog"},
    {"blog_title" : "Second Blog"},
    {"blog_title" : "Third Blog"},
    {"blog_title" : "Fourth Blog"},
    {"blog_title" : "Fifth Blog"},
  ]


  const liked_blogs = [
    {"blog_title" : "Second Blog"},
    {"blog_title" : "Third Blog"},
  ]
  
  


   render() {
      return (

        <div>

            {
                all_blogs.map(blog =>
                    liked_blogs.some(liked_blog => blog.blog_title === liked_blog.blog_title) ?  <div>This blog is liked</div> :  <div>This blog is NOT liked</div>)
            }

        </div>

     )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use a dictionary as you stated as a tag like below;

```
   const all_blogs = [
     {"blog_title" : "First Blog"},
     {"blog_title" : "Second Blog"},
     {"blog_title" : "Third Blog"},
     {"blog_title" : "Fourth Blog"},
     {"blog_title" : "Fifth Blog"},
   ]


   const liked_blogs = {
     "Second Blog": true,
     "Third Blog": true,
   }

 const innerContent = all_blogs.map(blog => liked_blogs[blog.blog_title] // this prevents inner loop and runs at O(1)
    ?  <div>This blog is liked</div> 
    :  <div>This blog is NOT liked</div>)
```